# Paid membership plans on registration page

Tags: users

I am creating a registration based website that has five membership plans.

Based on the selected membership plan, users have to pay the membership fee using Stripe payments.

How can I create membership plans and this kind of payment functionality?

Answer (score 3):

For membership process you can use the (paid for) [Moneyscripts](http://www.moneyscripts.net/ms_software/purchase/2185?destination=ms/cart) module.

> Membership Suite is the most comprehensive subscription software for
>   Drupal on the market and it is designed to seamlessly integrate your
>   site with all of the features of a professional Paid Membership
>   Subscription site. There is no other software available for Drupal
>   that can provide the stability, ease of use, and features that
>   Membership Suite offers.

Comment: Moneyscripts is pretty good.  I'm pretty sure this is possible with contributed modules (Commerce etc), but I think an answer going into that much detail is probably out of scope for this site.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you make use of the Commerce distribution and the [Commerce stripe](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe) contrib module? With commerce you can attach roles to products, so when a user buys your membership plan "A" he/she will automatically get assigned role "A".

Comment: the stripe module doesn't really have anything to do with the question